# how to acess the child element under the $(this) key word using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add the attribute title with a value of h3 to the href with class name (submit)

but i am not able to access the h3 text in each div which is selected with classname. please help out .

```js
 $(document).ready(
    function ()
        {
            $(".topic ").each(
            function()
                {
                    var title=$(this h3).text();
                    console.log(title)
                    
                    $(this ".submit").attr("title",title);
                }
            
            );
        }
    
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: `$('h3', this)`, or `$(this).find('h3')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find` with `$(this)` like below.

```js
$(".topic ").each(
  function() {
    var title = $(this).find('h3').text();
    console.log(title)
    $(this).find(".submit").attr("title", title);
  }

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
</div>

<div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
</div>

<div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
</div>

<div class="topic">
  <h3><a href="">Shoulder Arthritis</a></h3>
  <a href="" class="submit"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `.find()`.
The documentation can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

For example, your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(
function ()
    {
        $(".topic ").each(
        function()
            {
                var title=$($(this).find("h3")).text();
                console.log(title)

                $($(this).find(".submit")).attr("title",title);
            }

        );
    }

);
```

A little workaround can be done aswell, see here:

```
$(document).ready(
function ()
    {
        $(".topic ").each(
        function()
            {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var title=$('#' + id + ' > h3').text();
                console.log(title)

                $('#' + id + ' > .submit').attr("title",title);
            }

        );
    }

);
```

The `>` searches for a child of that element. 
So `$('#' + id + ' > .submit')` searches for a child of the element with the given id, that has a class submit.

Comment: 1. The extra `$( ... )` around `$(this).find('h3')` is absolutely unnecessary.   2.   the OP's HTML doesn't have (or need) IDs, and constructing selectors by string concatenation is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Unnecessary doesn't mean that it does not provide extra information. This way it is better to read for people that are not so familiar with jQuery.

Comment: No, it's *worse*.   jQuery is _designed_ to chain functions, and wrapping the `$(this).find('h3')` which already produces a jQuery object with _another_ call to jQuery has no benefit at all, and makes the code longer and slower.